# How was The HTML/Regex answer formatted - I can't see source of locked post?

Tags: support, markdown

I am curious: how was [this classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) about why you can't parse HTML with a regex formatted? Are we still able to use similar formatting? (Not that I'm likely to write as epic of an answer as that one; incidentally, after reading the answer I have no desire to summon tainted souls or open a breach into the dread realm of corrupt entities by trying to parse HTML with a regex).

I am aware that we can get the source of even locked posts like that one by looking at the revision history but looking at the source doesn't help much because the "interesting" part of the formatting isn't using "standard" markup (the only thing that "standard" markup is used for is for bold and italics).

Comment: Check the markup by clicking [edit]?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't, the post is locked so edit is disabled.

Comment: [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4b3a02a1-11b6-4442-b0f0-3602ea0432d2/view-source) - available from the revision history, as always. (not that it really helps here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not special formatting—it's a thing called "Zalgo Text" which abuses Unicode combining characters.

You can use [this page](http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html) to create your own.

Comment: -1 for not writing this answer in zalgo text